# How to resolve the while loop being terminated after the first execution in this code?

Tags: string

I've been working  on a String coder recently which converts a sentence to code with each number representing the letters position in the alphabet with space being 0. It has a while loop to restart the code after first execution but after entering 1, it asks to enter a string but before I can do that it asks to restart again.

```
import java.util.*;
class String_coder
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        String abc = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";int restart = 1, k;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //creates an array of every letter in abc
        char ABC[] = new char[abc.length()];
        for (k = 0; k < abc.length(); k++)  
        {
            ABC[k] = abc.charAt(abc.length() - (k+1)); //enters each letter into the array in order
        } 

        //Introduction
        System.out.println("Alkalyne Systems String Coder");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter any sentence and convert it to a code");

        while(restart==1)
        {
            int i = 0, j = 0, l = 0, alp = 0, abcPos = 0;
            String a = " ";

            //Inputs a String
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter a string");
            a = sc.nextLine();

            a = a.toLowerCase(); //Converts to lower case

            //creates an array of every character in the String
            char aConv[] = new char[a.length()];
            for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)  
            {
                aConv[i] = a.charAt(a.length() - (i+1)); //enters each letter into the array in order
            } 

            //Compares each letter in aConv with letter in abc to find position
            System.out.print("|");
            for (alp = a.length()-1;alp >=0;alp--)
            {
                for (abcPos = abc.length()-1; abcPos >= 0;abcPos--)
                {
                    if (aConv[alp] == ABC[abcPos])
                    {
                        System.out.print(abc.length() - (abcPos + 1));
                        System.out.print("|");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

            //restart
            System.out.println("Would you like to restart?");
            System.out.println("1 - Yes|0 - No");
            restart = sc.nextInt();     
        }

        //Exit Message
        System.out.println("Thank you for using String Coder");
        System.out.println("Have a wonderful day!");

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see what gets placed inside restart after the first loop run? Have you considered using ```hasNextInt()``` to check if there is.an integer?.[Example here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm)

Comment: Your are reading the value for `restart` from the Scanner with `sc.nextInt()` and I suppose, you are ending your input with RETURN. This return is used to determine the end of the integer, but it's not consumed from the scanner. So when you are asked to input a new string you read it with `sc.newLine()` which retrieves all data until the next occuring newline. But this is already waiting there in the scanner from the input of the previous number, thus an empty string is accepted as input